# How do I make Angular JS 1 routing work in ASP.Net MVC Core while running in IIS?

Tags: angularjs, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.Net Core MVC/Angular JS application I'm developing.

Everything works while I am developing and running through VS 2015 and IIS Express.

But when I publish the files to my local IIS and try to run through there it is not working.  The home page works fine and this is actually the final Angular otherwise route:

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
        templateUrl: "/app/views/home.html"
    });
```

I finally tracked down what is happening but I don't know why?
In my NavBar in my ASP.Net Core MVC _Layout.cshtml my `<a>` elements look like this:

```
<a href="#!/employee_list">Employees</a>
<a href="#!/non_employees">Non Employees</a>
```

This is working fine in Dev through VS 2015 and IIS Express.
The URLs look like this:

```
http://localhost:2352/#!/employee_list
```

and everything renders as it should.

But after publishing and running through full IIS (locally that is), the same `<a>` links give a URL like this:

```
http://lerd/#/!/employee_list
```

Notice the '/' between '#' and '!'.

so instead of '/#!/employee_list' I get '/#/!/employee_list.

What in the world is causing this?  Has anyone else experienced this?

---

I just noticed if you manually type the right URL in the browser and hit enter it sticks that extra slash in there.  So it's not really the application. It's the browser and maybe IIS.

Answer (score -1):

Well it seems that you need '#' on prod and '#!' in Dev.

So I did this in my layout file setting up the NavBar:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <li><a href="#!/employee_list">Employees</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/non_employees">Non Employees</a></li>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <li><a href="#/employee_list">Employees</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/non_employees">Non Employees</a></li>
</environment>
```

Comment: you enabled hasbang mode in your `config` of your angular application?? I don't think so that is needed then as you're not using `html5mode`..

Comment: Please what is hasbang mode?  Is this what would be doing that?  How do I turn it off?

Comment: that's why I asked, I guess you haven't used hashbang.. you should form your URL's like `#/employee_list` instead of `#!/employee_list`.. You can read about [hashbang mode here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-mode-default-mode-)

Comment: Better yet - stop using `href` and use proper routing to states.

Comment: Lex - no idea what this means.  Can you elaborate.  Unhelpful answers should be kept to yourself.